# is it possible to have more active tasks than number of cores on executor in Spark-Streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

[More Active task than number of cores](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pyniy.png)

We are using spark-structured streaming in our ingestion pipeline. We have enabled dynamic allocation property in our streaming application along with some other configs.
What I noticed is that I see a lot more active tasks on some executors than they have number of cores. I have attached the screenshot as well.
Is that normal ? We see some OOM errors on executors and wondering if the symptom has something to do with OOM error.
I also tried to look at the thread dump for one of the executor that has this symptom:
[Thread dump of one of the executor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jAoN.png)

Comment: I don't think its possible, and there are several Spark UI JIRAs to make it more accurate. For example, https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-30831. Also, your thread dump shows 4 active tasks as there should be.

Comment: thank you..makes sense..